# Issue with PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please fix my query, I cannot get it to work.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName`, `steamRealName`, `ip` = VALUE('$steamName', '$steamRealName', '$ip') where `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

I am trying to replace the users Steam Name, Real Name and IP address with the data in my db table but only for the columns where the Steam ID = $steamID.

I have used the following variables:

```
$steamID = $_SESSION['steamid'];
$steamName = $steamprofile['personaname'];
$steamRealName = $steamprofile['realname'];
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your query is wrong. It should be like:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName`='$steamName', `steamRealName`='$steamRealName', `ip` = '$ip' where `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

The syntax is :

```
Update tablename
set col1=val1,
    col2=val2,
    col3=val3
where condition
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your statement to a valid SQL-statement:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName` ='$steamName', `steamRealName` ='$steamRealName', `ip` = '$ip' where `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

Comment: Thanks heaps man for the super fast reply! This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` syntax should be:

```
UPDATE theTable SET col1 = col1Val, col2 = col2Val WHERE whereCol = whereColVal;
```

i.e.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName` = '$steamName', `steamRealName` = '$steamRealName', `ip` = '$ip' where `steamID` = '$steamID';
```

Also be aware that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be spoofed. You don't want to use this unescaped in your query.

Comment: Ah I see. So they might possible do something like a sql injection. I will escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName`= '$steamName', `steamRealName` = '$steamRealName' `ip` = '$ip' WHERE `steamID` = '$steamID';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having syntax issues,Try something like this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName` = '$steamName', `steamRealName` ='$steamRealName', `ip` = '$ip' where `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    UPDATE `users` 
    SET    `steamName`     = '$steamName', 
           `steamRealName` = '$steamRealName', 
           `ip`            = '$ip' 
    WHERE  `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

And try to use Prepared statements with PDO.

Comment: Do you have anything different with other answers?

Comment: So would I use that the same as I used it in my query? query = "UPDATE `users` etc.";

Comment: True ! Well, those answers were posted while I was writing answer in text file. anyway !

Comment: If you're asking about PDO, I suggest you to take a look at links ...http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET 
    `steamName` = '$steamName', 
    `steamRealName` = '$steamRealName', 
    `ip` = '$ip'
WHERE `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

But I would strongly recommend that you use prepared statements (see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Also, don't access `$_SERVER` directly, instead sanitize it:

```
$ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I will search up about how to properly use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code

```
UPDATE `users` SET `steamName`, `steamRealName`, `ip` = VALUE('$steamName', '$steamRealName', '$ip') where `steamID` = '$steamID'
```

Into

```
UPDATE users SET steamName='".$steamName."', steamRealName='".$steamRealName."', ip='".$ip."' where `steamID` = '$steamID';
```